# Conditional Probability Question given 3 Coins

Tags: probability, statistics

I had this question as a bonus problem on a previous exam and thought it was interesting, but I had no idea how to tackle it.

There are three coins in a box. One is a two-headed coin, another is a fair coin, and the third is a biased coin that comes up heads 75% of the time. When one of the three coins is selected at random and flipped, it shows heads. What is the probability that it was the first coin?

Comment: This is a problem for Bayes' theorem. No more no less.

Answer (score 0):

Bayes' theorem approach:

$P(A_1), P(A_2)$ and $P(A_3) = \frac{1}{3}$ - choice of coins

$P(B)$ = get heads

You are asked a question to find $P(A_1 | B)$

$P(A_1 | B) = \frac{P(A_1)*P(B | A_1)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(A_1)*P(B | A_1)}{P(B | A_1)*P(A_1) + P(B | A_2)*P(A_2) + P(B | A_3)*P(A_3)} = \frac{4}{9} $

Answer (score 0):

One possibility to think about it "in a very naive way" is as follows. The coins are numbered as 1, 2, 3 - say. Instead of the given experiment, we can imagine an equivalent one. Consider a hat with $12$ tickets in it, labeled as 
$$
1H,\ 1H,\  1H,\  1H;\ 
2H,\ 2H,\  2T,\  2T;\ 
3H,\ 3H,\  3H,\  3T.
$$
Choosing a coin $k$ has the same probability as choosing a ticket $k?$ from the hat. For each fixed $k$, getting head (H) for the coin $k$ has the same probability as picking the ticket $kH$.

Now we pass to the conditional probability. We have only

$$\color{red}{1H,\  1H,\  1H,\  1H};\  2H,\  2H;\  3H,\  3H,\  3H
$$
at our disposal. Picking $1H$ has then probability $$\frac 49\ .$$